# C# and WCF , where to learn about it?

Tags: c#, wcf

Its been a few weeks since I started learning C#, i know my way around visual studio, know things about classes, constructors, objects, played around with WPF and now think its time to learn some networking, say making a simple server/client application.

From what I understand winsockets are outdated and currently it is better to learn WCF ?

Maybe someone know some books, articles or tutorials about WCF for beginners where it would be explained step by stem from the ground up. :) Since all I was able to find were either rather complicated materials assuming that the reader it already a master-programmer or just coded supposed to be used as copy/paste without really explaining what it does.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, WCF is Microsoft's library of code to simplify the process of inter-machine and inter-process communication.  Pre-WCF, there were a number of frameworks you could use.  WCF gives them a consistent .net interface to simplify programming.

I recommend "Learning WCF", by Michele Leroux Bustamante.  It's as thick as a Bible, but it has accessible material about the different facets of WCF with lots of code samples.

Comment: note: "Learning WCF" is available on Safari Books online, for those of you who subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx

A very accessable group of tutorials, that cover the basics very well. Great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to reccomend [Pro WCF: Practical Microsoft SOA Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597028)
- i've been learning with wcf with it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned what I needed to know from the book [Windows Communication Foundation Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329484) by Craig McMurty, Marc Mercuri, Nigel Watling and Matt Winkler. It has good examples that you can use to produce your own web services and such. It requires some knowledge of C#, which you seem to already have.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28VS.90%29.aspx) my friend,If you have the patience to read the tutorials/articles in MSDN you can learn WCF very well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good beginner tutorials from MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(VS.90).aspx